# Can I use part of my data as lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, compare-and-swap

I have a large array (3e9 elements) of data, and I am updating its value in multiple threads. I just found out there are race conditions.

I think it is unnecessary to lock the whole function, as elements are independent of each other, the updating on `data[1]` and `data[234]` can be safely done at the same time.

I also found the most significant bit of each element in  `data[]` will never be used. Is it safe to implement a GCC atomic builtin lock on that bit?

My code is as follow but seems it is getting deadlocks.

```
const unsigned short LOCK_MASK = 1<<15;
unsigned short * lock = &(data[position]); 
unsigned short oldLock, newLock;

//lock 
do {
    oldLock = *lock;
    newLock = oldLock ^ LOCK_MASK;
} while ((oldLock & LOCK_MASK) || !__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(lock, oldLock, newLock));

//update data[position] here
...
...
...

//unlock
*lock ^= LOCK_MASK;
```

I have also read this post ([Lightweight spinlocks built from GCC atomic operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718138/lightweight-spinlocks-built-from-gcc-atomic-operations?rq=1)) and added `volatile` on my `data`

**EDIT** In my design, 0 means unlocked, and 1 means locked

Comment: All your reads before acquiring the lock need synchronization. In particular, `oldLock = *lock;` is wrong, that needs to be atomic. As it stands, the optimizer may assume that `*lock` never changes if `(oldLock & LOCK_MASK)` was true once.

Comment: A more conservative approach might be to allocate an appropriate number of real mutexes (or spinlocks or whatever mechanism you'd like to use) and use them to synchronize access to your data.  e.g. if you have an array of M mutexes, then just have each thread lock mutex #(i%M) before reading or writing value #i in the data array.  Tune the value of M until you find the smallest value for it in which contention for mutexes is still acceptably rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains a number of data races, including `oldLock = *lock` and unlocking the bit `*lock ^= LOCK_MASK`,
which fails to synchronize your updates to other cores by the absence of a release barrier.

Be aware that in addition to locking an array segment for write access, you also need to lock that segment for read access since reads and writes have to be synchronized.

> Is it safe to implement a GCC atomic builtin lock on that bit?

Multiple bits are required if you want to express separate states for read- and write access (*unlocked, read-locked x N, write-locked*).
A single bit limits locking to 2 states, *locked* and *unlocked*, which, based on your code, can be implemented with:

```
const unsigned short LOCK_MASK = 1<<15;

void lock_array_segment(int position)
{
    unsigned short *lock = &data[position]; // global array
    unsigned short oldLock, newLock;

    do {
        oldLock = __atomic_load_n (lock, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
        newLock = oldLock | LOCK_MASK; // set bit

    } while ((oldLock & LOCK_MASK) || !__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(lock, oldLock, newLock));
}


void unlock_array_segment(int position)
{
    unsigned short *lock = &data[position]; // global array
    unsigned short oldLock, newLock;

    oldLock = __atomic_load_n (lock, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    newLock = oldLock & ~LOCK_MASK; // clear bit

    __atomic_store_n (lock, newLock, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
}
```

The documentation for `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` says *In most cases, these builtins are considered a full barrier*. You need an acquire barrier here, so that should be covered.

Since your approach is based on spinlocking, it does not work well if you want to keep a read-lock for a longer time. In that case, consider a more straightforward approach with a separate mutex for each segment in your data array that needs locking.
If you want to give multiple readers access, consider using `std::shared_mutex` (C++17) or `boost::shared_mutex`.

Comment: didnt know the __atomic_* instructions before! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should consider more standard ways of locking (in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) or better).

Perhaps start by reading some [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) (at least for the concepts explained there).

Read about [atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) and [thread support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) in C++.

You could heuristically consider having a mutex for each segment of consecutive 1024 (or some other power of two) elements.

You might consider a [producer-consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) approach.